# What is the automation linked to?

Tags: fl-studio

How can I find out what an automation clip in FL Studio actually automates? The only way I have found so far is to go to the browser -> current project -> remote control, and there you have to look through all of them and see if the internal controller is set to the automation clip. There has to be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't changed the name of the channel, it will tell you the exact plugin, insert, and parameter it is automating.

If you've changed the name of the channel/pattern, you can go the browser > Current Project > Patterns > Initialized controls, it will tell you the following information about all of the things you are automating:

- Plugin Name
- Insert Number
- Name of Parameter

This also works with third-party plugins and will look something like this:

> Delay 3 - Insert 1 - Modulation rate

Unfortunately, there is no way as far as I know about finding this information out any other way.